# TypeError: an integer is required (got type _io.BufferedWriter) using pickle

Tags: python, file, serialization, pickle

the code:

```
import pickle
test = 3

>>> with open('test', 'wb') as file:
...     pickle.dumps(test, file)
```

and error reported unexpectedly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type _io.BufferedWriter)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're using the wrong function. Here's the docs:

> ```
> dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)
> ```
>
> **Return** the pickled representation of the object as a `bytes` object.

`dumps` converts the passed object to `bytes` and returns it. The error you get is when you pass a file argument to what `.dump` expects to be the pickling protocol, which is supposed to be an integer.

You'll want to use `pickle.dump`, which actually dumps to a file:

> ```
> dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)
> ```
>
> **Write** a pickled representation of `obj` to the open file object `file`.

```
with open('test', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(test, file)
```